# #Neo4j Deleting nodes/relationship while traversing using java API

Tags: neo4j, graph-traversal

I have a requirement to traverse all the nodes and delete all the nodes (and its relationships and connected nodes) based on certain criteria. For testing purpose (to make sure I can delete the nodes while traversing), i'm trying to just delete one node in the middle of the traverse and using another traversal to delete all the nodes and relationships attached to that node. I'm able to delete all the nodes and relationships but after that i'm getting IllegalStateException (Node has been deleted) when the loop is back to the 1st traversal. Is it possible to delete the nodes/relationships while traversing? If so, what is the effective way to traverse all nodes and delete some nodes along the way. Thanks in advance!

```
private void traverseGivenNode(Node node, TraversalDescription friendsTraversal) {

    for ( Node currentNode : friendsTraversal.traverse(node).nodes() )
    {
        if (currentNode.getProperty("name").equals("AAA")) {
            deleteNodeAndItsConnections(currentNode);

        } 
    }       
}

private void deleteNodeAndItsConnections(Node currentNode) {

    TraversalDescription traversal = graphDb.traversalDescription()
            .breadthFirst()
            .uniqueness( Uniqueness.NODE_PATH ).evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition() ).relationships( RelTypes.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING );


    for ( Node node : traversal.traverse(currentNode).nodes() )
    {
        deleteNode(node);
    }

    deleteNode(currentNode);

}

private void deleteNode(Node node) {
    Iterable<Relationship> allRelationships = node.getRelationships();
    for (Relationship relationship : allRelationships) {
        relationship.delete();
    }
    node.delete();
}
```

Comment: Please show your Cypher queries.

Comment: @cybersam Thanks for taking time to read my question. I'm using JAVA API for traversal. I have added the java code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to not delete anything until the traversals are complete. Instead, during the traversals, just add each node and relationship to be deleted to the corresponding HashSet. Afterwards, call Relationship.delete() on everything in the relationship Set, followed by Node.delete() on everything in the Node set.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond and your suggestions. Our graph will grow large in time so I was thinking more of adding a property in the node and relationship (something like mark for delete) and then may be run Cypher query to delete. I thought this might be faster compared to adding them in a collection and deleting them later. I'm going to test this out but do you happen to know which way is faster/efficient? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create set for relationships to be added and deleted.

```
Set<Relationship> removableRelations = new HashSet<Relationship>();
Set<Node> removableNodes = new HashSet<Node>();
```

Add nodes and relationships to be deleted in removableRelations  and removableNodes

then write below code for removing these:

```
for(Relationship removableRel:removableRelations){
            removableRel.delete();
        }
for(Node remNode:removableNodes){
            remNode.delete();
        }
```